moklist error: which keys to remove from secure boot key management and How?
similar answered questions

https://superuser.com/questions/1841890/moklist-error-volume-full-cannot-boot-asus-laptop
Couldn't Create Moklist: Volume Full - grub doesn't start at all
MokListRT error: volume full - delete and reinstall keys

My laptop is ASUS fx554ve was shipped with win10 license stored in BIOS.
i have been messing with dual boot for a long time never have i run into MOKLIST error
today i installed ubuntu 24.04 LTS from live USB on a preinstalled win10 OS.
after setup is completed i restarted that's when all the problems began
looking around i came to know that this error is due to NVRAM full, and 3rd site suggested that if i delete the forbidden keys it will work.
now because i do not want to loose win10 license i was unsure of deleting the forbidden keys, so i saved it to a file and then deleted it (forbidden keys 0, 0).
Grub did not load but boot went fine. i checked linux(ubuntu) has grub installed. checked if efibootmgr has unused entries. it has only 2 entries boot0000 windows and boot0002 ubuntu.
so a dead end.
restarting my pc again showed the MOKlist error. deleted the forbidden keys and the grub loaded and pc booted fine.
restarting my pc again showed the MOKlist error. persistent restart issues.
my questions

which keys can i safely delete?
is there a way to pick each one or do i have to go by classes (eg - forbidden, platform, etc)?
how to permanently delete them?

key management option details from bios
exact error

Please use edit and add to the question the version of Ubuntu being used.

@David edits have been made, as requested
